# Google Drive Service Account Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am getting error when I try to insert file to my drive shared public folder.

I am using Google Drive API for java.

My java code is :

```
File body = new File();
body.setTitle("ringeeapp");
body.setDescription("file uploadings");
body.setMimeType("text/plain");
body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(folderId)));
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("G:\\document.txt");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
System.out.print("file id is :" + file.getId());
Permission newPermission = new Permission();
// for showing files in browser that reason only using additional
// permission
newPermission.setValue("");
newPermission.setType("anyone");
newPermission.setRole("reader");
service.permissions().insert(file.getId(), newPermission).execute();
return file;
```

I get the following error:

```
error :`com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "file.permissions",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "Insufficient permissions for this file",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient permissions for this file"
}`
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Does the file upload? Is the problem on the permissions part or the file upload part.

Comment: I don't know where problem is acquired..

Comment: Any idea for that please help me ?

Comment: You will need to debug your code and find out if your problem is coming from the files().insert or the permissions().insert.   Either way the issue is with your permission of the file.   My guess is its the second item that is causing your problem.   You don't have permissions to insert the permissions.

Comment: What is `folderId` set to. My guess is that this is a virtual folder rather than a real user folder.

Comment: The problem probably comes from your newPermission.setValue(""); I don't see why you do that, when you want the document to be shared with anyone with the link. Can you remove that part and see if the permission is inserted ?

Comment: folderId is real user folder i am getting folder id from url link.